# Изменить сегмент в ld

Tags: c, gcc, компоновщик, ld

По умолчанию `ld`, как я понял, считает, что в `%ds` находится 0 и соответственно компонует программу на языке C с этим значением. Как его изменить в настройках компоновщика, чтобы при изменении `%ds` на другое значение в программе (например, 0x07c0), она работала корректно?

На всякий случай уточню, что речь идёт о написании программы наподобие загрузчика.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понял, напрямую задать `%ds` нельзя, но зато для секции .data можно указать VMA, что расшифровывается, как Virtual Memory Address. После этого, компоновщик будет загружать секцию по LMA (Load Memory Address), но адреса переменных, находящихся в этой секции, при обращении к этим переменным из программы, будут начинаться с VMA, а не с LMA.

Рассмотрим такой пример: в `%ds` устанавливается в коде значение 0x07c0, секция .text загружается по адресу 0x7c00, .data находится сразу после .text. Тогда необходимо установить VMA равным размеру секции .text. После этого, например, переменная, находящаяся в самом начале секции .data, при обращении к ней из кода программы, будет иметь адрес `%ds*16+Размер секции .text=0x7c00+Размер секции .text`. Это соответствует фактическому расположению переменной. Полный код скрипта компоновщика:

```
ENTRY(main);
SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x7C00;
    /*установлен только LMA, VMA такой же */
    .text : AT(0x7C00)
    {
        _text = .;
        *(.text*);
        _text_end = .;
    }
    /*VMA=SIZEOF(.text) LMA=ADDR (.text) + SIZEOF (.text)*/
    .data (SIZEOF(.text)) : AT(ADDR (.text) + SIZEOF (.text))
    {
        _data = .;
        *(.bss);
        *(.bss*);
        *(.data);
        *(.rodata*);
        *(COMMON)
        _data_end = .;
    }
    .sig : AT(0x7DFE)
    {
        SHORT(0xaa55);
    }
    /DISCARD/ :
    {        
    *(.note*);
        *(.iplt*);
        *(.igot*);
        *(.rel*);
        *(.comment);
    *(.eh_frame);
    }
}
```

Подробнее про LMA и VMA можно почитать по этой ссылке https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Output-Section-LMA.html